# Right version (Framework and target) for Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have several devices with different versions of Android (4.4 or higher).

On [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/android-api-levels/) I read that the project should be set up like this:

> *Minimum Android Version <= Target Android Version <= Target Framework*

and

> *We recommend that you always compile with the latest available Target Framework version*.

I tried 4.4 <= 4.4 <= 8.0 but in this way, however, I get a runtime error on 4.4 devices for: "button.Background.SetTint()" (it's right I suppose).

If I set the Target Framework version to 4.4 Visual Studio warns me of error for "SetTint()" but I can not install nuget package "Xamarin.Google.Play.Services.Base" (even if I try to install version 32.961.0:
"Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the pack age does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.").

Comment: If you set target android version to 4.4 it means that your app will not work properly on devices above 4.4. The best way is to set target to 8.0 or 8.1 (latest one). And also targeting only 4.4 is not a good idea as only [12%](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) as of February 5, 2018 of the total users will be able to use your app properly

Comment: if I set the version to 8.0 I get an error on the 4.4 devices for the SetTint() method

Comment: `SetTint()` might not be available/supported in 4.4. You have to do something like `if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= 19) { //do something } else { SetTint() }`

Comment: It's right! But how should I set up Visual Studio to make sure that the application works on devices that have a version of Android> = 4.4?

Comment: I don't quite understand you now. Please post the exact error that you are getting now.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi You have it reversed, an App compiled against and targeting API4.4 would be enabled to access 94.3% of the current Google Play users.

Comment: @Giovanni https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521960/xamarin-create-application-for-android-4-vs2017-15-5-5/48522385#48522385 You will need to test against a 4.4 Device/Emulator to ensure that you are not using APIs that exist in later versions

Comment: Your numbers are OK, but I suggest `4.4 <= 8.0 <= 8.0`, because it'll prevent future headaches. Read [Google's article from "Related Links"](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) on the same topic. Xamarin has the naming a bit mixed up and calls both compile and target just "target" which is confusing.

Comment: @SushiHangover he has min and max sdk as 4.4 (one and only one) so how is that going to be 94.3%

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi An app that sets the `targetSdkVersion` to 4.4 would allow APIs that target 4.4, 5.0, 5.1, ... 8.1 to run the app. You of course can not use any APIs features above 4.4 in your app: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I'm a bit confused ... I start again. First consideration: I have a series of business devices with Android 4.4 (or higher) and I would like to develop an application for business use. Initially I had set 4.4 <= 8.0 <= 8.0 in Visual Studio. Not having received any errors in compilation I distributed the application but it didn't work on devices with Android 4.4: error for "SetTint ()". To be sure not to use functions not supported on devices with version 4.4 I thought to set the SDK version to the minimum version available on my devices but is this the correct thing to do?