# Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version 7.1" framework in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I encountered the error as stated in the title from my Visual Studio Code on Mac. Detailed error message is as below:

[image]

I have already targeted my project to Android 7.1 but the error keeps displaying.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I only have to click on "Project" menu --> "Restore Nuget Package" and the compilation is successful.

Comment: I had the same issue about 8.1 as reported here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137371/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-mono-android-version-v8-1-framework-error/p1?new=1.  I was one day at work, building worked fine, next day, I took my laptop home and try building and had this issue.  Next day, I took my laptop back to work and building was working again.  No idea why this.

Answer (score 0):

Following the post [Xamarin create application for android 4 (VS2017 15.5.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521960/xamarin-create-application-for-android-4-vs2017-15-5-5/48522385#48522385?newreg=ccb00512a1324a37bb7f8d92c9d0ad12) solved it for me. Remember to restore the packages after that.